# Use custom hook in callback or in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have:

```
rules={{
            required: 'This is required.',
            validate: (value) => daoExists(value),
          }}
```

with `daoExists`, I need to check GraphQL endpoint and if it returns true, validation succeeds, otherwise some error message. I am using `useQuery` hooks from Apollo client for such queries, but now I have a problem, because `daoExists` can't be a hook. So, what I am doing is I create a `daoExists` as normal function. Something like this:

```
export const daoExists = async (name: string): Promise<ValidateResult> => {
  const query = `
    query Daos($name: String) {
      daos(where: {name: $name}){ 
        id
      }
    }
  `;

  const data = await fetch(subgraphUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query,
      variables: { name: name },
    }),
  });

  const daos = await data.json();
  return daos?.data?.daos?.length > 0 || 'Dao with this name already exists';
};
```

Which I really don't like to use `fetch` and I want to continue using `useQuery` hooks, but I can't. I even tried creating `useCallback`, but then I can't use `useQuery` in my `useCallback.`

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: rules=`{{ ... }}` looks like JSX but you're not supposed to run async functions when calling `render()`. You need to use an external `isValid` state instead.

Comment: Yeah, but problem is something else.  I don't want to have `daoExists` function. I already have a function much better than that that is a custom hook. Don't I have any way to use that custom function for that validate ?

Comment: A hook is asynchronous by definition and therefore unsuitable to be called during `render()`. What the render() method does is synchronously(!) render the app state to the screen. It's not supposed to wait on network operations. `onChange` changes app state -> useEffect runs dao query -> isValid state is updated -> component re-renders using `validate: () => isValid`

Comment: @ChrisG yes, but my hook can't be called inside a useEffect, so that's the problem...

Comment: It looks like you need [`refetch`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#refetching); Your `useQuery` line is directly in the component function as it's supposed to, and in your useEffect function you call that to update the query result.